# How to test requests are resolved in a specific order

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

I'm trying to write a Cypress test that validates that a specific request is resolved before another.  Here is my code:

```js
it('Module 1 should load before Module 2', () => {
  // Delay Module 1 by 5 seconds
  cy.intercept('module1.js', (req) => {
    req.on('response', (res) => {
      res.setThrottle(5000);
    });
  }).as('module1');
  cy.intercept('module2.js').as('module2');

  cy.visit('/');

  // Module 1 should load before Module 2 even though it's delayed
  cy.wait('@module1');
  cy.wait('@module2');
});
```

This test is predicated on `cy.wait()`s resolving in order, but that does not appear to be the case. If I switch the two `cy.wait()`s to the following, the test still passes.

```js
cy.wait('@module2');
cy.wait('@module1');
```

I've even tried having the second wait occur in the `then()` block of the first, but it still doesn't seem to care about order.

```js
cy.wait('@module2').then(() => {
  cy.wait('@module1');
});
```

**How can I test that two requests are resolved in a specific order?**

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps timestamp the responses and wait for them together

```js
it('Module 1 should load before Module 2', () => {
  // Delay Module 1 by 5 seconds
  cy.intercept('module1.js', (req) => {
    req.on('response', (res) => {
      res.setThrottle(5000);
      res.timestamp = Date.now()
    });
  }).as('module1');
  cy.intercept('module2.js', (req) => {
    req.on('response', (res) => {
      res.timestamp = Date.now()
    });
  }).as('module2');

  cy.visit('/');

  // Module 1 should load before Module 2 even though it's delayed
  cy.wait(['@module1', '@module2').then(interceptions => {
    expect(interceptions[0].timestamp).to.be.lt(interceptions[1].timestamp)
  })
});
```